# EF Core 5 filter Include and ThenInclude

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following function for user authentication:

```
internal static async Task<bool> AuthenticateUser(GameUser user, int userId, string token)
{
    await using var dbContext = new dabernaContext();

    var dbUser = await dbContext.Users

        // Referred users and their games
        .Include(u => u.InverseReferrerNavigation)
        .ThenInclude(u => u.GameUserLinks)
        .ThenInclude(gul => gul.Game)

        // User games
        .Include(u => u.GameUserLinks)
        .ThenInclude(gul => gul.Game)

        // User itself
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId && u.Token == token)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (dbUser == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    dbUser.LastLoginTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    user.CachedGames = new List<Game>();
    user.CachedUserRefferals = new List<User>();

    var games = dbUser.GameUserLinks
        .Where(gul => (DateTime.UtcNow - gul.Game.StartTime).TotalDays <= 30)
        .Select(gul => gul.Game);

    foreach (var game in games)
    {
        user.CachedGames.Add(game);
    }

    foreach (var refferedUser in dbUser.InverseReferrerNavigation)
    {
        user.CachedUserRefferals.Add(refferedUser);
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    return true;
}
```

My goal in this function is to first check if this user can be authenticated using the given token then get and add his games to a cached variable then do the same for each user referred by this user (to count the games played by each referred user)

The above code is not tested and might work but it has two problems:

1. The query is not optimized, it gets all users referred by this user then search in the `game_user_link` table then another search in the `game` table. What I want is to only get the rows where `game.StartTime` is at most 30 days ago or less.
2. I want a way to count the referred users games count in the past month until now instead of querying the rows which is not needed in my case

[image: user-game-many-to-many-link]

Edit to database structure is possible if it's needed for performance.

Comment: There's some work for you to do before this can be a question. "Might work" isn't enough. If it doesn't we're wasting our time. Further, show some first efforts so we see where you need help. From a broader perspective you should consider untangling this confusing mixture of authentication and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var period = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);

//to get games only
var games= dbUser.GameUserLinks
       .Where(gul=>gul.StartTime<=period)
       .Select(gul=>gul.Game);

//You can minimize your code into:

var dbUser = await dbContext.Users
    // Referred users and their games
    .Include(u => u.InverseReferrerNavigation)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.GameUserLinks)
    .ThenInclude(gul => gul.Game)
    // User itself
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId && u.Token == token && 
     u.Game.StartTime<=period)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```